# Can MediaCodecSDK be used to add overlay to video in Android?

Tags: android, video-processing, android-mediacodec

Say you have a 20 second video (perhaps taken with the device camera) and you want to add an overlay in to the video.

(The overlay would simply be a normal raster image, i.e. an Android `Image` ([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image)).)

You want to create a new video, with the overlay as part of the video image, and save the video.

In fact, can MediaCodec SDK be used to do this job?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec

In the past, you would usually use FFMPEG for such a problem, but that is a mess and slow.

Is MediaCodec possible here?

Since it is "new" I just can't find any information on this.....

Comment: random older [article](https://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/) on MediaCodec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is possible using MediaCodec. 
For a start, take a look at the DecodeEditEncode example [from here](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)

This example is shows how to resize a vide using a OpenGL ES shader. What you want to do is render your overlay over the video also using a OpenGL ES shader.

Another good source for examples on MediaCodec [can be found here](https://github.com/google/grafika)

Here you can find some examples on how to use basic rendering techniques. Look at the Hardware scaler exerciser.

When you have the video part up and running, this is probably where the actual struggle starts since there are no standard methods to render text in OpenGl ES. I'd probably just draw text to a Canvas and make a texture out of it, probably is slow though.

If you have a static overlay, like a watermark, you could create it beforehand and ship as a resource.

Comment: This is fantastic information Chris, thanks.  Amazing!

Comment: One small detail Chris, regarding text - for sure, we would very simply render that, first, in an unrelated process.  (It could be text, drawing, whatever. Just some pixels.)  So, we would have an `Image` , ie https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image .  I believe, that is then "relatively easy" to mix in to the video?   (ie, it is easy for you ;)  )

Comment: I'm glad this is helpful.

Comment: If you have a Texture/Bitmap it is relatively easy yes, you just have to get it into a OpenGL ES texture and use alpha blending. There should be many examples on how to load a bitmap into a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.

Comment: What is probably harder is getting video de/encoding up and running. Also, if you have never worked with OpenGL ES, the learning curve is very steep

Comment: Right - understood.